# how do i clear a whole column of records in Microsoft access?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, executenonquery

There's a column in my database called Points with numbers and id like to set all the records in this column to zero. how would i accomplish this ?

Here's what iv done so far,

```
public static void clearPoints()
    {
         OleDbConnection myConnection = GetConnection();
         int count = 0;
        string myQuery1 = "Update AnswerTable  SET Points= " + count+ "'";
        OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery1, myConnection);

        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception in DBHandler", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: `Update AnswerTable  SET Points=0`

Comment: have you tested your program? what is the error? i cannot see any.

Comment: on closer look: you missed one single quote `Points= '"`

Comment: Thanks brada!! it worked god bless you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust your query string to

```
string myQuery1 = "Update AnswerTable SET Points=0";
```